# Can we change the default mouse cursor highlight color

Tags: 20.04, gsettings, mouse-pointer, gnome-settings-daemon

If we enable mouse highlight

`❯ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer true`

on pressing and releasing `Ctrl` key the mouse cursor gets highlighted.

Can we change the highlight color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible.

It is from the gnome-shell theme being used.

The configuration depends on whether you use default shell-theme that came with fresh installation or are you using any custom shell theme.

you need to look for below portion from the css file being used.
Note that I have already changed the color to black in the below content.

```
.ripple-pointer-location {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #629fea; }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi, i am using the adapta nocto eta theme and its gnome-shell.css file there was no such attribute. But I added your lines. Default color was black before adding, I made color orange, but no change took place. any idea what to do for my theme

Comment: sure, i have unticked the accept mark

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aahnik/c740a9e064938d96a14e8371b779182c

Comment: this is the file [click here](https://gist.github.com/aahnik/c740a9e064938d96a14e8371b779182c)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113913/discussion-between-aahnik-daw-and-unknown).

Comment: 1. I have added the ripple pointer location as said by u, it was not there from before. And 2. I am using zorin os, which is based on Ubuntu.

Comment: thank you very much for the effort. I was distro hopping. planning to switch back to ubuntu for multiple reasons