# How do I customize the circle shown in the "locate pointer" feature (in Gnome)?

Tags: gnome, mouse-pointer, pointers

So when I am on multiple monitors and each monitor has a bunch of stuff on it, it can be difficult to notice the little propagating circles when I use the locate pointer feature (left ctrl).

Is there a way to customize it or make it larger, change the color, etc.?

Edit/add: The DE is GNOME.

Comment: What is your desktop environment??

Comment: if it is GNOME, then https://askubuntu.com/q/1281355/739431

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent answer in the other question. Sorry I had omitted the DE. Yes, this question was for GNOME, though I also use KDE sometimes.

Comment: @UnKNOWn So I tried editing the css file like mentioned in the other answer, and then I refreshed the theme, but it doesn't seem to work...